# How to pass a dynamic number of arguments into a function

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I want to pass an unknown number of arguments to a function.  The function is basically structured as:

```
public void test(string x, params string[] y)
{
    //code
}
```

I need to pass an unknown number of arguments into the y input.  In some cases, I may have 2 y's, in others I could have 20 y's in the format of

```
test("test", arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], arg[3] ... arg[20]);
```

Any suggestions on how to enter a varying number of y inputs into the above function?  I'm attempting to automate a process and c# is new to me.

Comment: @SonerGönül His question is what to do when he doesn't know the size of `args` at compile time.  In such a case, that code doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: Stck all your items into an array or list, and pass it in, then loop through it inside your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to pass `arg`:

```
test("test", arg);
```

Comment: As basic as the solution was, i didn't realize I could just pass the arg in by itself.  I thought I had to specify the index as well.  Thanks!  Now if I could just get the 3 hours that I spent on this back, that would be great.

Comment: You got it actually. And here it is: Don't focus on a question for 3 hours, while you can ask it at SO, or some other programming forums, or even when you can google it. This is a lesson that cost you 3 hours of your golden time. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use a list, you can add the elements to the list and then send it to your function 
see that link
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)